# geom_col chart not showing negative values below x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I must be doing something very silly but I can't figure out what. I am trying to do a simple column plot of 3 values per plant (x axis variable) where the 3 values can be -ve or +ve. Somehow, geom_col chart is showing all values going up from x axis instead of showing -ve values going down and +ve values going up from x axis. See code and chart image I got:

```
coef_plot1 <- df_mtx %>%
  filter(test_parameter=="weight_dry") %>%
  pivot_longer(c(avg_trend_coeff, min_trend_coeff, max_trend_coeff), names_to="trend_coeff_type", values_to="trend_coeff_value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=plant, y=trend_coeff_value, fill=trend_coeff_type))+
  geom_col(position='dodge')

print(coef_plot1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `trend_coeff_value` seems to be `factor` or `character`.

For example,

```
dummy <- data.frame(
  type = rep(c("avg", "max", "min"),3),
  plant = rep(c("Fle", "Mc", "Sw"), each = 3),
  val = c(-1.5,-4.5,0.01,-0.47,-1.39,0.02,-0.06,-0.32,0.02)
)

  type plant   val
1  avg   Fle -1.50
2  max   Fle -4.50
3  min   Fle  0.01
4  avg    Mc -0.47
5  max    Mc -1.39
6  min    Mc  0.02
7  avg    Sw -0.06
8  max    Sw -0.32
9  min    Sw  0.02
```

dummy %>%
ggplot(aes(x = plant, y = val, fill = type)) +
geom_col(position = "dodge")

[image]

If change `val` to character or factor,

```
dummy %>%
  mutate(val = as.factor(val)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = plant, y = val, fill = type)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

So, try adding `mutate(trend_coeff_value = as.numeric(trend_coeff_value))` before `ggplot` part

Comment: perfect, thank you!